# updating SqlClient dataset table with OracleClient dataset table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle, datatable

I use a dbDataAdapter to populate a DataTable from an unlinked oracle database.

I have a dbDataAdapter that I want to insert rows into an SQL Server table using SQLCommandBuilder.

I have been trying all day to update the DataTable that references the SQL Server table with the data from the Oracle DataTable so that I can insert the rows.

I've been googling all afternoon with no satisfaction.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your dataset are typed datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a linked server to oracle from SQL server and then use a simple select statement.

Comment: Does that mean it cannot be done?  Linking the servers is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, I used DataTable.Load(OracleDataReader) to populate the DataTable then I used SQLBulkCopy to insert the rows into the database.

No linked server necessary